# SDL2 KMSDRM starts but draws nothing on Raspberry Pi 3B

Tags: c++, linux, raspberry-pi, sdl, sdl-2

I wrote this simple test program that clear to grey, using `KMSDRM` support of `SDL2`:

```
#include <SDL.h>

#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include <SDL_opengles2.h>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using std::clog;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    auto init_re = SDL_VideoInit("KMSDRM");
    if (init_re != 0)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("SDL2", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480,
                                          SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if (nullptr == window)
    {
        std::cerr << "SDL_CreateWindow(): " << SDL_GetError() << '\n';
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES);
    auto gl = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);
    clog << "create OpenGL context " << gl << endl;
    auto make_current_re = SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(window, gl);
    clog << "make current ctx returned " << make_current_re << endl;
    clog << "OpenGL version: " << (const char *)glGetString(GL_VERSION) << ", GLSL "
         << (const char *)glGetString(GL_SHADING_LANGUAGE_VERSION) << endl;

    glClearColor(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    size_t frame_count = 0;
    SDL_Event e;
    bool should_break = false;
    while (!should_break)
    {
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&e))
        {
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                should_break = true;
            else if (e.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
                if (e.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                    should_break = true;
        }

        frame_count += 1;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
        clog << "frame " << frame_count << endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(2ms);
    }

    SDL_GL_DeleteContext(gl);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}
```

The test program runs and prints frame count log, but does not draw a 640x480 piece of grey.

Is there any further things for KMS that is required to do to make it draw?

In addition, it draws a mouse pointer on top left corner, which is really out of my expectation. But the pointer does not move with my mouse. How to make the mouse run in `KMSDRM` mode?

Below are system/config I run:

- 32-bit Raspbian bullseye, newest update.
- To make the world clean, I uninstalled the whole X server.
- SDL2 installed from Raspbian repo by apt.
- Related settings in `config.txt`:

  ```
  dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d,composite
  max_framebuffers=2
  gpu_mem=256
  ```

Comment: Any reason you aren't pumping the message queue via `SDL_WaitEvent()`/`SDL_PollEvent()`/`SDL_PumpEvents()` during the draw-loop?  Also, given that you're trying to use OpenGL ES (via the `#include <SDL_opengles2.h>`), does anything change if you [set `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK` to `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL2/SDL_GLprofile) before `SDL_CreateWindow()`?

Comment: @genpfault So I have to pump the event system even if I don't directly use it? For the GL API, if I don't make any specification, would I expect to get a "default working" context that have some "basic" GL functions, or I would get nothing working?

Comment: @genpfault I tried to set `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK` to `SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_ES`, still draw nothing. In addition, I printed OpenGL and GLSL version by `glGetString`, it gives me `OpenGL ES 2.0 Mesa 20.3.5` and `OpenGL ES GLSL ES 1.0.16` which looks healthy.

Comment: @genpfault And I also added event poll inside mainloop, the mouse cursor still won't move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm so stupid that I forgot to call swap buffers `SDL_GL_SwapWindow(window)` at the end of each frame. That's the reason why everything is not refreshed.